# How to assign factors for each column and calculate rowmeans based on the factor level

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame which I want to calculate row-means according to certain conditions, 
example:

```
df= 
rownames    A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
r1  1   2   3   4   5   6
r2  1   2   3   4   5   6
r3  1   2   3   4   5   6

treatment= factor(rep(c("A","B"),each=3))
```

I want to get the means of each row based on the factor level of treatment, data as below:

```
rownames    A   B
r1  2   5
r2  2   5
r3  2   5
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `melt` from `data.table`.  The `measure` argument can take multiple `patterns` to convert to 'long' format, grouped by 'rownames' and specifying the columns in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `mean`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^A", "^B"), value.name = c('A', 'B'))[, 
              lapply(.SD, mean), rownames, .SDcols = A:B]
#   rownames A B
#1:       r1 2 5
#2:       r2 2 5
#3:       r3 2 5
```

NOTE: The output is a `data.table` which can be converted to `data.frame` (`setDF`) as showed in the OP's output

---

Another option is `split` from `base R`

```
sapply(split.default(df[-1], sub("\\d+", "", names(df)[-1])), rowMeans)
#     A B
#[1,] 2 5
#[2,] 2 5
#[3,] 2 5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(rownames = c("r1", "r2", "r3"), A1 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L), A2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L), A3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L), B1 = c(4L, 4L, 4L
), B2 = c(5L, 5L, 5L), B3 = c(6L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("rownames", 
"A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: thanks. How if the patterns are not very strict. like A1, A2, A3 is first group, A4, A5, A6 is the second group but not B1, B2, B3. it would be better if it could be done according to the position of factors, I mean without the pattern match

Comment: @user5240 That is a different case.  In that case, position is better

Comment: do you know the way to do this by position? akrun

Comment: @user5240  For those cases, simply `sapply(split.default(df[-1], rep(1:2, each = 3)), rowMeans)`

Comment: thanks, It worked on the cases we have same number of replicates. how about some measures have only 2 and some have 4 replicates. my main idea is to connected columns (replicates) from the treatment with same factors (conditions), then pass the factor to control the calculation of means or standard deviations. but could figure out a proper way.  do you have any idea or clue on this? @akrun

Answer (score 0):

In base R using `grep`:

```
sapply(levels(treatment), function(a) rowMeans(df[,grep(a, names(df))]))

#     A B
#[1,] 2 5
#[2,] 2 5
#[3,] 2 5
```